# What does "r" do at the end of a vim search-and-replace command?

Tags: regex, vim

What does the `r` do at the end of this vim search and replace command: `:%s/foo/bar/r` ?

Comment: I found it on this page, under the section "Substituting": http://bullium.com/support/vim.html

Comment: Try `:help :s_flags` in vim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find out the meaning of the **r** at the end just type `:help :substitute` in `vim` :

```
[r]     Only useful in combination with `:&` or `:s` without arguments.  `:&r`
        works the same way as `:~`:  When the search pattern is empty, use the
        previously used search pattern instead of the search pattern from the
        last substitute or `:global`.  If the last command that did a search
        was a substitute or `:global`, there is no effect.  If the last
        command was a search command such as "/", use the pattern from that
        command.
        For `:s` with an argument this already happens: >
                :s/blue/red/
                /green
                :s//red/   or  :~   or  :&r
```

So in your case the command `:%s/foo/bar/r` has absolutely the same effect as `:%s/foo/bar/`  which will change **ONLY the first** occurence of `foo` to `bar` in every line containing the search pattern (which is here `foo`)